# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'META' in Django Project

Tags: python, django

I am working on a blog in Python-Django. When I run the command "python manage.py runserver" in my project folder, I get  following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    server = request.META.get('wsgi.file_wrapper', None)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'META'
```

I have not seen this error anywhere. Should I include Meta class in my installed_apps? How do I do it?

Here is my manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from django.http import request

server = request.META.get('wsgi.file_wrapper', None)
if server is not None and server.__module__ == 'django.core.servers.basehttp':
    print('inside dev')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dj1.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

and settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for dj1 project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(l8*%h2ids25q=x9qb7%x+(b=$1mm&yg8b5ga^0u2w9*+k%+9-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dj1.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dj1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

Comment: do you know what was the original intent of this piece of code? as far as i tell, you wanted to see what server was running your django code. if you still want that, or have something else in mind, you can edit your question and i'll try to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a big code bulder.

This piece of code here makes no sense inside the manage.py

```
from django.http import request

server = request.META.get('wsgi.file_wrapper', None)
if server is not None and server.__module__ == 'django.core.servers.basehttp':
    print('inside dev')
```

Perhaps you copied it from somewhere, and didn't put it where it belongs.

This piece of coude would belong in a view. It will never work inside manage.py, and makes asolutely no sense there.

*[EDIT]*
ALSO, in a view, you should *NOT* include the import, or you'll get the same error. That means, don't include this `from django.http import request`